# How check the restSecureServicesPort is available?

Tags: windows, service, server

I've installed a application with a service on a Windows Server 2012 R2. The status of the service is paused. When I start the service, he runs for two seconds and he's again paused.

In the instructions from the manufacturer is written:

> Note: If the service shows as paused, check the restSecureServicesPort is available.

What does that mean? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could mean, that you application hosts a REST service on this Windows service. REST (REpresentational State Transfer) is a simple stateless architecture that generally runs over HTTP. This means it needs a port on which the application listens and receive data. This port is probably already busy and another application uses it. To view all busy ports you could use the `netstat` command via the command line on your server. But first you have to find out on which port your application wants to listen (maybe through some documentation of the application).

After this you could check if it's possible to change the port of your application or the port of the application which occupies this port.

Hope this helps!